# Code seems to duplicate processes when in a cron job

Tags: linux, shell, centos, sh

I have a problem with my shell code. The purpose of the code is to automatically start the server if one is suddenly is offline due to a crash. **The code works perfectly when you just simply execute it via ./script.sh & however! When I set a cron job with the script, it begins to start several processes of the srvexecutable**

Unfortunately the processes have the same name, so I have to base it off the process ID and the process ID's location. Hence "realpath" is implemented.

Here is the code. I would extremely appreciate it if someone helped me fix this bug.

```
# Created by Lorenc!

# Server List
srvloc_1="/home/user/srv1"
server_1="/home/user/srv1/srvexecutable"

srvloc_2="/home/user/srv2"
server_2="/home/user/srv2/srvexecutable"

# Loop Iterator And Server Array!
servers=0
declare -a SRV

for word in $(pidof srvexecutable); do

    SRV[servers]="$(realpath /proc/$word/exe)"
    #echo ${SRV[$servers]}
    let servers++
done

if [ "$servers" -ge 2 ]; then 
    echo "that's $servers processes"
    exit 
else
    if [ "$servers" -le 1 ];
    then
        echo "Currently $servers processes."
        if [ "$servers" -eq 0 ];
        then
            echo "No servers online! Booting both now."
            cd $srvloc_1
            nohup $server_1 &
            sleep 1
            cd $srvloc_2
            nohup $server_2 &
            exit
        else
            if ${SRV[0]} == $server_1
            then
                echo "Starting $server_1 as it is not online!"
                cd $srvloc_1
                nohup $server_1 &
            else    
                echo "Starting $server_2 as it is not online!"
                cd $srvloc_2
                nohup $server_2 &
            fi
        fi
    else
        echo "Both servers are running. Beautiful."
    fi
fi
```

Comment: http://shellcheck.net/

Comment: ...to give you a quick preview: Needs a `#!/bin/bash` shebang; needs much, *much* more quoting; the last `if` statement isn't in a test context, so it's trying to run `${SRV[0]}` as a command with `==` as its first argument... etc.

Comment: ...also, using `[ "$foo" -le "$bar" ]` is bad form; since you're requiring bash anyhow, `(( foo <= bar ))` is much, **much** easier-to-read. Without the quotes (which is how you're mostly using it), by contrast, it's not just bad form but buggy.

Comment: ...finally, you'd be much, much better off if you didn't try to use cron for this at all, and used a proper process supervision system -- upstart, systemd, runit, daemontools, supervisord, or one of many, many others.

Comment: I'm pretty much learning SHELL. Hence many of the mistakes. But thanks, I'll see what I can do in around 40 minutes.